# Angular disable parent scroll when child is open

Tags: angular

I made a popup which appear when button in parent component is clicked. It have absolute position and 80% alpha, blured background. I would like to prevent parent scroll because this popup have 100% width and height and it doesn't look good when the background is shifting :P

It looks something like this:

```
<parent-component> <-- Disable scroll of this boy 
    <child-popup *ngIf="some condition"><child-popup> <-- When this is open
</parent-component>
```

Comment: Have you tried some simple CSS with `overflow: hidden;`?

Comment: Did it using `VievEnscapulation.None` and add `overflow: hidden` to `body` and `html` in child component